# Godot error 'can_instance: Cannot instance script because the project assembly is not loaded.'

Tags: godot

I have just setup a new Godot 3.5 2D pixel project. The project is bare bones except for a TileMap and a Sprite with 2D collision, and a script I wrote called DragAndDropController.cs I continue to get this error:

```
E 0:00:03.437   can_instance: Cannot instance script because the project assembly is not loaded. Script: 'res://scripts/DragAndDropController.cs'.
  <C++ Error>   Method failed. Returning: __null
  <C++ Source>  modules/mono/csharp_script.cpp:2894 @ can_instance()
```

My entire DragAndDropController (unfinished) is as follows:

```
using Godot;
using System;

public class DragAndDropController
{
    public void _Input(InputEvent @event)
    {
    // Mouse in viewport coordinates.
    if (@event is InputEventMouseButton eventMouseButton)
        GD.Print("Mouse Click/Unclick at: ", eventMouseButton.Position);
    else if (@event is InputEventMouseMotion eventMouseMotion)
        GD.Print("Mouse Motion at: ", eventMouseMotion.Position);
    }
}
```

I get no errors when I open the solution in Visual Studio. I have updated VisualStudio/.NET SDK to 2022/7.0 respectively. I have deleted the solution files repeatedly and used Project > Tools > C# > Create Solution to rebuild. I made sure the folder root name, project name, and assembly file are all the same without invalid characters or spaces. Why am I still getting this error?

Comment: Didn't work with c# in godot but I think you should inherit your class from some `Node` class, add the node to node tree and attach your script to it to load it correctly. That is a usual workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved.

- Parent the Sprite to a 2D Control node.
- Inherit the Control class in the script and attach to the Control node.

```
        public class DragAndDropController : Control {}
```

- Make sure to have Visual Studio Community 2022 as the default external editor, and change Editor Settings to Mono(MS Build) with VS Build Tools 2022.